# Google Assistant command triggering action in Android application

Tags: android, xamarin, google-assistant-sdk

Is there any way of creating a Google Assistant command that will trigger an action in my application? So for example, when user has my app installed and says "Ok Google, create number" it automatically turns on my app and triggers some CreateNumber() method which creates a random number.

Comment: In my knowledge, no you cannot do that!

Comment: Is their any update ? Google introduced actions.xml where you can add actions as deep link.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate your devices with the Google Assistant, then you need to create a single webhook for the smart home API to access the device data for your users

https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/